# ServerSocket.accept gives me multiple connections although I am only connecting once

Tags: java, sockets, executorservice, serversocket

I have an ExecutorService that creates a new Thread for every connection:

```
boolean running;
Socket socket;
ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ss=new ServerSocket(port);
while(running){
        socket=ss.accept();
        executorService.submit(new ConnectionThread(socket));
        }
```

ConnectionThread constructor looks like this, run method is too long to post here:

```
Socket socket;
ConnectionThread(Socket socket){
            System.out.println("connectionThread running...");
            this.socket=socket;
        }
```

when I refresh the page in my browser, the ConnectionThread constructor tells me that multiple threads have been created. Why does that happen?

Comment: Please post code of your `ConnectionThread` class, especially the constructor, as well as any error messages/stack traces you get

Comment: posted the constructor, but I'm not getting any errors, just around 11 times "ConnectionThread running..." in my console

Comment: Somebody else is connecting. Are you using a well-known port? Print the accepted socket and find the process with `netstat`. BTW Your connection thread isn't running at the point you say it is. That starts inside the `run()` method, not the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because the browser opens several TCP connections for different purposes.